# SSIS pre-evaluation phase taking long

Tags: sql, performance, ssis

I have a data flow that contains a OLEDB source (statement generated through a variable) which calls a stored procedure.
In SSMS, it takes 8 minutes but the package itself takes 3 times longer to complete. 
I've set the validation (DelayValidation) to true, so it still does it at run time. Ive also set the validation of the metadata in the data flow component, as well as in the connection manager. 
The data flows have ReadUncommitted on them as well. 
I`m not sure where else to look, any assistance on how to make this run faster would be great.

Comment: Can you post the SSIS logs, indicating where you think there is a performance issue.

Comment: Logging is not enabled for the package, but when running with dtexecui the process takes a long time during pre-execute phase. I'm looking to reduce or remove that step completely from the package as that is where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I don't know the answer but found many things to try when I searched on "ssis pre-execute phase stuck" for example. Have you run profiler against the database to see what it is doing in this time? What database is it against?

Comment: I have enabled logging and have profiled the database. There seems to be a gap in the time to receive the metadata since its bieng done with a link to another database, as nothing comes up in the logs or the profile, just a huge time gap. I'm hoping that the +50 points will motivate your ESP powers.

Comment: What amount of  time is being spent in pre-execution in the phase and how much is spent actually running the package? Also can you post an image of the overall package. I've run into and fixed this problem before. I'll need to know more if I'm going to be able to help.

Comment: Are you running this package in SSIS or are you using SQL agent to run the package?

Comment: This is SQL Sever 20?? Do you have the ability to modify the stored procedure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect the real problem is in your stored procedure, but I've included some basic SSIS items as well to try to fix your problem:

- Ensure connection managers for OLE DB sources are all set toDelayValidation ( = True).
- Ensure that ValidateExternalMetadata is set to false
- DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize to correspond to the table's row sizes
- DROP and Recreate your destination component is SSIS
- Ensure your stored procedure has SET ANSI_NULLS ON
- Ensure that the SQL in your sproc hits an index
- Add the query hint OPTION (FAST 10000) - This hint means that it will choose a query which will optimise for the first 10,000 rows – the default SSIS buffer size
- Review your stored procedure SQL Server [parameter sniffing](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html).

**Slow way:**

```
create procedure GetOrderForCustomers(@CustID varchar(20))
as
begin
  select * from orders
  where customerid = @CustID
end
```

**Fast way:**

```
create procedure GetOrderForCustomersWithoutPS(@CustID varchar(20))
as
begin
  declare @LocCustID varchar(20)
  set @LocCustID = @CustID

  select * from orders
  where customerid = @LocCustID
end
```

Comment: Why do you recommend skipping validation?  I find it valuable, albeit sometimes slow.  Have you seen it cause problems, outside the specific scenario where a table or field does not exist at compile time of course?

Comment: I have not seen it cause a problem except that it's slow. Setting the ValidateExternalMetadata property to False provides more granular control over your data flow than setting the DelayValidation property to True. When the ValidateExternalMetadata property is set to True (the default), it helps avoid locking issues when your package uses transactions. For this reason, you might want to stick with using DelayValidation at the task level, unless you have some overriding need to work at the component level.

Comment: OPTION (FAST N) was the fix for me.