# SSIS package stuck in validation phase beginning when trying to import/export excel files

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, ssis, export

On our servers (windows 2016, SQL reporting server 2016, Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016) we run 2 SSIS packages. 1 imports data from an excel file to the database and 1 exports data from the database to an excel file. Both are xlsx files.

We run this exact package on TST, ACC, RES and PRD (same server and access setup). We didn't have any issues until a week ago the packages on PRD just kept on getting stuck in the "beginning validation phase" of the Dataflow Task. The other environments are fine.

We've determined that it is not a problem in the application since a simple read package that we created for this issue, gave the same problem. It doesn't seem to be an access issue either. The account that runs the script is sysadmin in SQL and local admin on the fileserver.

We also tried
•   Only using one import flows instead of two in Data Flow task: no change https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/781c855f-833e-4578-a43a-1729482bbabd/dtspipeline-validation-phase-is-beginning-but-never-stop?forum=sqlintegrationservices

•   Set connection managers for OLE DB sources are all set toDelayValidation to True: no change [SSIS pre-evaluation phase taking long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305676/ssis-pre-evaluation-phase-taking-long/19821281)

•   Set  ValidateExternalMetadata is set to false for Excel Sources: no change [SSIS pre-evaluation phase taking long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305676/ssis-pre-evaluation-phase-taking-long/19821281)

•   Reinstall Microsoft Access Database Engine on server: no change

•   Tested reading a flat file (txt) which worked without issue.

We're fresh out of ideas so any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
When manually trying to run the import/export wizard (and selecting excel file) I get "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application". Investigating this message as well.

Comment: In the other, "fine", environments what happens when you manually try to run the import/export wizard?  Do you get a different outcome?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  We have 5 different package exporting to Excel and they all get stuck with the last message being OnInformation "Validation phase is beginning."  This came up when we were upgrading from Sql Server 2012 to 2019 and we no longer are allowed to have access to the local disk for the SSIS server.  I am convinced that it has something to do with that, but it fails one in 50 times right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you had no problem reading a text file then that would point me to the excel driver (32 or 64),  however I would think if that was the issue you would see a connection error. Do this as test.

1. Go to the console and open excel on the server. This will let you know if you have some licensing issue or something preventing excel from opening on the server.
2. Import a small amount of data into SQL server from excel using the import data into a test database (or just make a test table). Be sure to use the same driver you are using in the SSIS package.

Comment: Hey Perry,

Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly I'm not able to open the excel file on the server since office has not been installed there (only the Microsoft Access Database Engine)

However an interesting message popped up when I tried to run the import wizzard: "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application". This was not the case on the other servers. So that really points at the driver again.